# Bidirectional list

Tags: list, visual-c++

The following code calculates the sum of the elements of the unidirectional list items greater than 3 and smaller than 8 and the result of the sum is changed the beginning of the list.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct List 
{
    int num;
    List* nItem;
};

int Input()
{
    int number;
    cout << "Enter the number: "; cin >> number;
    return number;
}

void MakeList(List **head, int n)
{
    if (n > 0) {
        *head = new List;
        (*head)->num = Input();
        (*head)->nItem = NULL;
        MakeList(&(*head)->nItem, n - 1);
    }
}

void Print(List* head)
{

    if (head != NULL)  {
        cout << head->num << " ";
        Print(head->nItem);
    }
}

List* Add_start(List* head, int index, int elm)
{
    List* p = new List;
    p->num = elm;
    p->nItem = NULL;

    if (head == NULL)  {
        head = p;
    }
    else  {
        List* current = head;
        for (int i = 0; (i < index - 1) && (current->nItem != NULL); i++) 
        {
            current = current->nItem;
        }
        if (index == 0)  
        {
            p->nItem = head;
            head = p;
        }
        else  {
            if (current->nItem != NULL)  {
                p->nItem = current->nItem;
            }
            current->nItem = p;
        }
    }

    return head;
}

int Sum(List* head)
{
    int sum = 0;
    List* p = head;
    while(p) {
        if ((p->num > 3) && (p->num < 8))
            sum += p->num;
        p = p->nItem;
    }

    return sum;
}

void DeleteList(List* head)
{
    if (head != NULL) {
        DeleteList(head->nItem);
        delete head;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n = 10;
    List* head = NULL;

    cout << "Enter 10 number to the list\n" << endl;
    MakeList(&head, n);
    int sum = Sum(head);
    head = Add_start(head, 0, sum);

    cout << "\nList: ";
    Print(head);
    cout << endl;

    DeleteList(head);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

How can I do the same operation with a bidirectional list?

Comment: The description says: "_list items greater than 3 and smaller than **5**_", while the code: `((p->num > 3) && (p->num < 8))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Notes**:

- A bidirectional (or double linked) list, also has a member pointing to the previous node: this is the whole difference between the 2 list types (as a consequence the first element - or the one at the *left* of the list, will have this member pointing to `NULL`). So, when such a node is created/inserted into a list, this new member should be set as well (I commented in the code places where this happens), for the new node and for the one following it (if any).
- I modified the way of how a list is created - `MakeList` replaced by `_MakeList2` + `MakeList2`; the *underscore*(_) in `_MakeList2` specifies that it's somehow *private* (convention borrowed from *Python*) - it's not very nice, but I thought it's easier this way
- I don't have *Visual Studio* on this computer, so I used *gcc*. It complained about [`system`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/277bwbdz(v=vs.100).aspx) function so I had to add `#include <stdlib.h>`
- I renamed some of the identifiers (`List` -> `Node`, `Add_start` -> `AddNode`, `nItem` -> `nNode`) either because the new names make more sense, or their names are consistent
- I tried to keep the changes to a minimum (so the solution is as close as possible to your original post)
- I enhanced (by adding an additional argument: `toRight` (default value: 1)) the `Print` func, so it can iterate the list both ways - I am iterating *right to left* (for testing purposes) before deleting the list
- I corrected some (minor) coding style issues

Here's the modified code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

struct Node {
    int num;
    Node *pNode, *nNode;  // Add a new pointer to the previous node.
};

int Input() {
    int number;
    cout << "Enter the number: "; cin >> number;
    return number;
}

Node *_MakeList2(int n, Node *last=NULL) {
    if (n > 0) {
        Node *node = new Node;
        node->num = Input();
        node->pNode = last;
        node->nNode = _MakeList2(n - 1, node);
        return node;
    }
    return NULL;
}

Node *MakeList2(int n) {
    return _MakeList2(n);
}

void Print(Node *head, int toRight=1) {
    if (head != NULL) {
        cout << head->num << " ";
        if (toRight)
            Print(head->nNode, 1);
        else
            Print(head->pNode, 0);
    }
}

Node* AddNode(Node *head, int index, int elm) {
    Node *p = new Node;
    p->num = elm;
    p->pNode = NULL;  // Make the link between this node and the previous one.
    p->nNode = NULL;

    if (head == NULL)  {
        head = p;
    } else {
        Node *current = head;
        for (int i = 0; (i < index - 1) && (current->nNode != NULL); i++) {
            current = current->nNode;
        }
        if (index == 0) {
            p->nNode = head;
            head->pNode = p;  // Make link between next node's previous node and the current one. 
            head = p;
        } else {
            if (current->nNode != NULL)  {
                p->nNode = current->nNode;
            }
            p->pNode = current;  // Make the link between this node and the previous one.
            current->nNode = p;
        }
    }
    return head;
}

int Sum(Node* head) {
    int sum = 0;
    Node *p = head;
    while(p) {
        if ((p->num > 3) && (p->num < 8))
            sum += p->num;
        p = p->nNode;
    }

    return sum;
}

void DeleteList(Node *head) {
    if (head != NULL) {
        DeleteList(head->nNode);
        delete head;
    }
}

int main() {
    int n = 10;
    Node *head = NULL, *tail = NULL;

    cout << "Enter " << n << " number(s) to the list" << endl << endl;
    head = MakeList2(n);
    int sum = Sum(head);
    head = AddNode(head, 0, sum);

    cout << endl << "List: ";
    Print(head);
    cout << endl;

    tail = head;
    if (tail) {
        while (tail->nNode != NULL)
            tail = tail->nNode;
        cout << endl << "List reversed: ";
        Print(tail, 0);
        cout << endl;
    }
    DeleteList(head);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: one question, the result of the sum in the unidirectional list must to be the same of the bidirectional list?

Comment: Well, yes, if the list elements are the same (the question doesn't mention anything different required for the bidirectional list). For this problem, having a bidirectional list (and thus being able to traverse it both ways) makes no difference. The only thing that differs is: _simple linked_:  `N0 -> N1 -> N2 -> ... -> Nn -> NULL`, _doubly linked_: `NULL <- N0 <-> N1 <-> N2 <-> ... <-> Nn -> NULL` (with `head` pointing to `N0`) the link types between the nodes, and where is possible to navigate from one node, but for the same values of the `num` field they will both have the same sum.